# Has anyone gotten Node.js debugger to be able to use typescript sourcemaps with a source code directory structure?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a directory configuration and set of build/launch options which will enable VSCode debugger to let me set breakpoints in and debug through TypeScript files that are not in the root directory of the source tree.

For example, take a simple Express application:

```
(root)
|
+ app.ts
+ app.js
+ app.js.map
|
+ routes/
    |
    + index.ts
    + index.js
    + index.js.map
```

When I run this in VSCode under the debugger, having set sourceMaps to true in the launch config, I am able to set breakpoints in app.ts, but not in index.ts.

Has anyone been able to get so you can set breakpoints and debug through a typescript file in a non-root directory? TIA

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted your launch.json, I will paste here one that works for me and allows to debug back and forth nodejs application with lots of nested folders:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch Server",
        // Type of configuration.
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server/app.ts",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": ["--nolazy", "--harmony", "--harmony_default_parameters"],
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
        "sourceMaps": true,
        // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/dev",
        "request": "launch"
    }]
```

The points of interest here are: `program`, `sourceMaps`, `outDir`. Make sure they are all set and correct.

Also you might check how your maps look like (I assume they are fine as you can debug root file). But just in case below is js.map for one of the files nested in folder below root (`server` being root folder, ):

```
{"version":3,"sources":["server/middleware/Server.ts"],......,"sourceRoot":"/Users/someuser/projects/myproject"}
```

Hope this helps.